# Xcode - iOS - Is there a way to compare contents of two apps?

Tags: xcode5, filemerge

I know I can use FileMerge to compare app pages. Is there a way to compare entire apps? I have an old version and a new version. There are a lot of changes, and comparing page by page is not proving useful.

Thanks

Comment: What do you specifically need? Compare app sources? Bundles?

Comment: well, really, everything. What you mention plus xib/storyboard sources, data models, textual source files, such as XML, CSV..

Comment: well, as much as possible...

Comment: git? mercurial? subversion?

Comment: my understanding of the systems is that they are very good at showing differences in versions of the same app, but can they also differentiate between different apps? For example, I have an english, french and greek version of an app. There are enough differences that make it tedious to use FileMerge. I don't know if a SCCS would help..

Comment: just locate the first app's dir. Init repo. commit. Then paste second to it. commit. Then look diff between commits. I also recommend to use SourceTree app for this.

Comment: This looks great.Thanks Petro. I am playing around with it, and it's not bad.. If you write this as answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not SourceTree app advertisement. SourceTree just fits good.
Init repository for your first app with `git init`. From now you can work with it from SourceTree. Open SourceTree, on bookmarks window select "Add repository", switch to tab add working copy and add your working copy, actually). Do your first commit.
Place contents of folder of your second app into your newly-created repository. Overwrite all, if you are asked about. In SourceTree do your second commit. Now you can:
1) See diff
2) Save diff
3) Reverse any of differences
4) Switch between versions etc.

Comment: Theres a lot to learn, but I got my first repo set up, and I'll add others today. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: You are welcome. This book contains description of almost all git features http://git-scm.com/book if you are not familiar with them.